# Update manager won't update, Software Center will not open

Tags: server, apt, software-sources

```
Could not initialize the package information

An unresolvable problem occurred while initializing the package information.

Please report this bug against the 'update-manager' package and include the following error message:

'E:Type 'n.' is not known on line 3 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pmcenery-ppa-oneiric.list, E:The list of sources could not be read., E:The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.'
```

Comment: We need more information, like, what command did you run or what you did to get this error message?

Comment: whats the content of the file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/pmcenery-ppa-oneiric.list` ?

Comment: it just say permission denied when i enter it in terminal

Comment: When I right click show update i get this message

Comment: @DajaionLee Can you post the content of the file as requested by fossfreedom?

Comment: I fixed it by sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pmcenery-ppa-oneiric.list via terminal and taking n. out of the text

Answer (score 2):

OP answered in a comment

> I fixed it by sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pmcenery-ppa-oneiric.list via terminal and taking n. out of the text